# Read and write cookies with Ruby on Rails 4 AND Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to read and write cookies with a Ruby on Rails 4 application and Nginx. The first time Ruby on Rails sets a cookie and later Nginx should be able to deliver specific content depending on that cookie (without running through Rails). And vice versa.

How can I write and read unencrypted cookies with Ruby on Rails? It's easy to use encrypted cookies and sessions but I can't get it working with unencrypted cookies.

PS: Security is not an issue at all with this specific application. Actually I want the user to be able to read the cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use following code, it won't store cookie in a session. So, it will be plain text:

```
cookies[:test] = "test"
```

You can check it with

```
curl -I <URL>
```

It will return headers including

```
Set-Cookie: test=test; path=/
```

BTW. I believe by default even session cookies aren't encrypted. You have to configure your app for them to be encrypted. However, they are base64 encoded.

You can take a look at this article:
http://www.andylindeman.com/2013/02/18/decoding-rails-session-cookies.html